# pdf assets for xcode from psd with vector layers (or layer groups)

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, vector, assets

Subj. I have a bunch of psd files with vector layers, which are purposed to be IOS application assets.
I need to get all this layers into pdf files for Xcode assets. I found some related solutions for that case:

- Slicy (http://macrabbit.com/slicy/) it can generate png assets from any psd layers, marked (named) for extraction.
- Adobe PHotoshop generator tool (looks like it uses same naming (marking) syntax , going to try it, but i doubt it can make pdf assets (maybe it can?)

Help me with that case, I'll appreciate any advice!

update: i'm a developer, but i'm doing it by hand because of deadline lol :)